# Is there a way to duplicate and concat df groups (orders) by occurences of items (in order) in separate df?

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with optimising code, because mine solution is very slow.

I have 2 dataframes. One with 6 columns - 1 column with main items and 5 columns with items recommended. Second df contains sales data per order (each product in separate row).

I need to check what product is flaged as a "main" product, which products are recommended and which are just additional ones. If there is more than 1 main product in order, I need to duplicate that order and set only 1 main product per duplicate.

I tried using pandas for that and found working solution however I used itertuples, spliting both dfs by main items etc. It gaves my right result, but 1 order is computing for almost 2 secs and I have more than 1mln of them.

```
promo = pd.DataFrame({'main_id':[2,4,6],
        'recommended_1':[1,2,8],
        'recommended_2':[8,6,9],
        'recommended_3':[10,9,10],
        'recommended_4': [12,11,11],
        'recommended_5': [6,7,8]})

orders = pd.DataFrame({
'order':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c'],
          'product':[1,2,3,2,4,9,6,9]
})

promo['recommended_list'] = promo[
['recommended_1','recommended_2',
 'recommended_3','recommended_4', 
 'recommended_5']].values.tolist()

flag = pd.DataFrame(
{'flag':orders['product'].isin(promo.main_id)}
)

flaged_orders = pd.concat([orders,flag], axis=1)

main_in_orders = pd.DataFrame(
flaged_orders.query("flag").groupby(['order'])['product']
.agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
)

order_holder = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in main_in_orders.itertuples():
    for item in row:
        working_order = orders.query("order==@index")
        working_order.loc[working_order['product']==item,'kategoria']='M'
        recommended_products = promo.loc[promo['main_id']==item]['recommended_list'].iloc[0]
        working_order.loc[working_order['product'].isin(recommended_products), 'kategoria'] = 'R'
        working_order['main_id'] = item
        order_holder = pd.concat([order_holder, working_order])
        # NaN values in this case would be "additional items"
print(order_holder)
```

So, can u help me with faster alternative? Pointing me in some direction would be awesome, because I've stuck at this for some time. Pandas is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to be able to have all the rows you want, then use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to create the column 'kategoria'. The first `merge` would be to keep only the rows with the 'main_id' in the 'product' column with a `inner` method, then the second `merge` would be to create the duplicates if multiple 'main_id' for a same 'order' with a `left` method.

```
df_mainid = orders.merge(promo, left_on='product', right_on='main_id', how='inner')
print (df_mainid)
#  order  product  main_id  recommended_1  recommended_2  recommended_3  \
# 0     a        2        2              1              8             10   
# 1     b        2        2              1              8             10   
# 2     b        4        4              2              6              9   
# 3     c        6        6              8              9             10   
#
#    recommended_4  recommended_5  
# 0             12              6  
# 1             12              6  
# 2             11              7  
# 3             11              8
```

So you get only rows with a 'main_id' in the 'product', then

```
df_merged = orders.merge(df_mainid.drop('product', axis=1), on=['order'], how='left')\
                  .sort_values(['order', 'main_id'])
print (df_merged) 
#    order  product  main_id  recommended_1  recommended_2  recommended_3  \
# 0      a        1        2              1              8             10   
# 1      a        2        2              1              8             10   
# 2      a        3        2              1              8             10   
# 3      b        2        2              1              8             10   
# 5      b        4        2              1              8             10   
# 7      b        9        2              1              8             10   
# 4      b        2        4              2              6              9   
# 6      b        4        4              2              6              9   
# 8      b        9        4              2              6              9   
# 9      c        6        6              8              9             10   
# 10     c        9        6              8              9             10   

#     recommended_4  recommended_5  
# 0              12              6  
# 1              12              6  
# 2              12              6  
# 3              12              6  
# 5              12              6  
# 7              12              6  
# 4              11              7  
# 6              11              7  
# 8              11              7  
# 9              11              8  
# 10             11              8
```

you get the duplicated 'order' if several 'main_id'. Finally, create the column 'kategoria' with `np.select`. The first condition is if 'product' is equal to 'main_id' then 'M', the second condition is if the 'product' is in the different column starting with 'recommended' is 'R'. At the end, `drop` the columns like recommended to get the same output than your `order_holder`.

```
conds = [ df_merged['product'].eq(df_merged.main_id) , 
          (df_merged['product'][:,None] == (df_merged.filter(like='recommended'))).any(1) ]
choices = ['M', 'R']
df_merged['kategoria'] = np.select( conds , choices , np.nan)
df_merged = df_merged.drop(df_merged.filter(like='recommended').columns, axis=1)
print (df_merged)
   order  product  main_id kategoria
0      a        1        2         R
1      a        2        2         M
2      a        3        2       nan
3      b        2        2         M
5      b        4        2       nan
7      b        9        2       nan
4      b        2        4         R
6      b        4        4         M
8      b        9        4         R
9      c        6        6         M
10     c        9        6         R
```